# Iterate throught 3 conditions in pandas

Tags: pandas, loops, classification

I have a data frame and I want to iterate on the info of column1 to separate it on three categories (State labs, Private labs, Institution labs) which are going to be added to another column.Column1 goes like this (example):

> LABORA
> -PRIV LAB1
> -ARKANSAS
> -CDC LAB
> -PRINCETON
> -LAB
> -PRIV LAB 2
> -FLORIDA

and so on...

My code (at least the relevant part) goes like this:

```
laborat=cov["LABORA"]      #cov is my df, and LABORA the column im interested in
cond1=laborat.str.contains("PRIV", case=False) #condition to look for string PRIV on each cell
cond2= laborat.isin(["STATE 1", "STATE 3",...."STATE N"])  #condition to look for if a string is in a list of states 
cond3= i have no clue
```

my for loop goes like this:

```
privados=[]

for row in laborat:
    if cond1 == True:
       privados.append("PRIVATE LABS")
    elif cond2 == True:
       privados.append("STATE LABS")
    #else:
     #  privados.append("INSTITUTION LABS")

cov["privados"]= privados
```

So, if row has PRIV string, goes to PRIVATE LABS, if string is in list of states, goes to STATE LABS, and any other which doesnt meet these, goes to INSTITUTIONAL LABS with *its previous* name.

So, I have tried and cant get it. My knowledge of python is basic. When running it, I get this message:

---

> 

```
 ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-22-fa9897c323bc> in <module>
>       2 
>       3 for row in laborat:
> ----> 4     if cond1 == True:
>       5        privados.append("PRIVADOS")
>       6     elif cond2 == True:
> 
> D:\ArchivosProgramas\Anaconda\envs\pandas_playground\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py
> in __nonzero__(self)    1476     1477     def __nonzero__(self):
> -> 1478         raise ValueError(    1479             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "    1480            
> "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
> 
> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,a.bool(), a.item(), 
> a.any() or a.all().
```

I would appreciate any help at all. Sorry if its too basic, looked for something similar and didnt find anything.

UPDATE: Thank you so much for your help.  I´ll put some comments here. My data structure is a csv file with 100 columns and about 150 000 rows. The column im interested in is of different types of labs, I only adapted it to the USA, hoping for it to be more comprehensive, everything in that column are strings.

Comment: You're iterating for each row but the conditions are being checked for the entire series. This `cond1`  is a series of boolean whereas here `if cond1 == True:` you're trying to assert for a single bool value. Hence the error.

Comment: The same can be achieved through np.where() very easily without iteration. Check it out.

Comment: we don't know your data structures , but from your error message it seems if you use cond1.values ==True   it will be ok , you can try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use boolean indexing.  Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'lab': ['private lab 1', 'arkansas', 'cdc lab', 
             'princeton', 'lab', 'private lab 2', 'florida']}
)
```

Now, apply each condition, and use a default value of Institution.

```
states = {'arkansas', 'florida'}

# 0. initialize
df['lab-type'] = df['lab']
df['rule'] = 0

# 1. private labs
mask = df['lab'].str.contains('private', case=False)
df.loc[mask, 'lab-type'] = 'Private'
df.loc[mask, 'rule'] += 1

# 2. state labs
mask = df['lab'].isin(states)
df.loc[mask, 'lab-type'] = 'State'
df.loc[mask, 'rule'] += 10

# 3. default is institutional lab
# df['lab-type'] = df['lab-type'].fillna('Instution')

print(df)


             lab   lab-type  rule
0  private lab 1    Private     1
1       arkansas      State    10
2        cdc lab    cdc lab     0
3      princeton  princeton     0
4            lab        lab     0
5  private lab 2    Private     1
6        florida      State    10
```

UPDATE:  I added initialization in 'Step 0'.  The column `lab` is from the original data, and `lab-type` is just copied from `lab`.  Then, we apply updates to `lab-type`, and also update the rule (i.e., reason) for each update in the `rule` column.

If rule == 0, then we did not have enough info to change the value.  If the rule is not a power of 10, then we updated that row more than once.

Comment: Update: First, thank you so much for those who gave me an answer.

Comment: Couldnt figure how to implement np.where in strings. @jsmart, it has worked perfect, thank you, but how can i retain original institution name? That is, if any case not falling on states or private, i want them to keep their name, any idea how can this be done? one solution would be just to make a copy...i guess...

Comment: I added "Rule 0" (marked with # 0.) and commented out "Rule 3" in response to your comment.

Comment: Great!  If this works for you, please consider accepting the answer (to give it a green check).  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Yes, it is right but i dont see how to do that (accept the answer).

Comment: I'm not sure, actually.  I think you would see a grey check mark next to each response -- just click on the check mark next to the preferred answer.  I think the person who posted the question has a different view than everyone else.  Thanks again.